# Can't get every exif data from tif-file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tiff, exif

Iam trying to get the Title and subject of tif-Files, but it seems like iam not getting every data. Iam looking for "Titel" and "Betreff" (Eng. "title" and "subject" i guess). Are these values ​​hidden in XPTitle, XPData or XPSubject? If so, how do I get the data?

[image]

I tried following from another topic:

```
    import exifread
    # Open image file for reading (binary mode)
    f = open(tif, 'rb')

    # Return Exif tags
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)

    # Print the tag/ value pairs
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print ("Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag]))
```

What i got:

```
Key: Image ImageWidth, value 967
Key: Image ImageLength, value 979
Key: Image BitsPerSample, value 32
Key: Image Compression, value Uncompressed
Key: Image PhotometricInterpretation, value 1
Key: Image Make, value XXXXXX
Key: Image StripOffsets, value 406
Key: Image SamplesPerPixel, value 1
Key: Image StripByteCounts, value 3786772
Key: Image XResolution, value 100
Key: Image YResolution, value 100
Key: Image PlanarConfiguration, value 1
Key: Image XPosition, value 4294967295/42579232
Key: Image YPosition, value 858993459/9308555
Key: Image ResolutionUnit, value Pixels/Centimeter
Key: Image Software, value XXXXXX
Key: Image SampleFormat, value Float
Key: Image XPTitle, value [70, 0, 108, 0, 117, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 122, 0, 101, 0, 110, 0, 122, 0, 0, 0]
Key: Image XPComment, value [0, 0]
Key: Image XPSubject, value [50, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, 37, 0, 59, 0, 32, 0, 49, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, ... ]
```

After running exiftool i know the data is in XP Subject. Any ideas how i can get the plain text in python?

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.29
File Name                       : 01_Fluo.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 3.6 MiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:07:06 11:06:04+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:07:15 21:05:56+02:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2021:07:10 01:49:54+02:00
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 967
Image Height                    : 979
Bits Per Sample                 : 32
Compression                     : Uncompressed
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Make                            : XXXXX
Strip Offsets                   : 406
Samples Per Pixel               : 1
Strip Byte Counts               : 3786772
X Resolution                    : 100
Y Resolution                    : 100
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
X Position                      : 100.8700038
Y Position                      : 92.28000039
Resolution Unit                 : cm
Software                        : XXXXX
Sample Format                   : Float
XP Title                        : I NEED THIS AS STRING (Company Name)
XP Comment                      :
XP Subject                      : AND THIS AS STRING (20 %; 100 mW)
Image Size                      : 967x979
Megapixels                      : 0.947
```

Comment: Run `exiftool` on the file and that will tell you exactly what is in there and whether XMP, EXIF, IPTC or otherwise.

Comment: Ok, that helped. Now i know its in XP Subject. Can i read that somehow with python?

Comment: Maybe click `edit` under your question and add in the output from `exiftool` so we can see too...

Answer (score 0):

```
convString = tags["Image XPSubject"].values
convString = [x for x in convString if x != 0]
s = "".join([chr(c) for c in convString])
```

XPSubject, XPComment and XPTitle are just Lists with ASCII-Code in it. So, after filtering the zeros, the Code above solved my problem.